# How to make the clicked element stick to the top of the header?

Tags: jquery

My requirement is that , i need to make the clicked elment stick to the top of the Header .

For example if i click on Header 3 , it must hide the Header 1 and Header 2 and make the Header 3 stick to the top , and when scrolled back Header 2 and Header 1 must be visibale .

Similarly when clicked on click on Header 2 , it must hide the Header 1 and make the Header 2 stick to the top , and when scrolled back Header 1 must be visibale .

Could you please let em know how to proceed ??

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
   $('.my-collaspible').on('collapsibleexpand', function() {
      //  $('.my-collaspible').not(this).collapsible("collapse")
           $('.my-collaspible').animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, 'slow');

   });
 });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/jWaEv/70/

Comment: Is there any wahy to resolve this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So this is the original draft, seemingly functional :

http://jsfiddle.net/xr6fn9cw/

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  var item = $('.my-collaspible');

  item.on('collapsibleexpand', function() {

    item.not($(this)).collapsible('collapse').hide();
    $(this).collapsible('expand');

  })
  .on('collapsiblecollapse', function() {

    item.show();
  });

  $(window).scroll(function() {

    item.collapsible('collapse').show();
  });
});
```

Not very optimised with that scroll but that would be an easy fix. But it turned out there's some strange dynamic going on when using this :

```
item.on('collapsibleexpand', function() { ...
```

Creates a huge amount of calls, overflowing Chrome's maximum stack size as can be read in the comments. So here's a workaround to reduce them to a single call each time :

http://jsfiddle.net/3skm69qf/

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  var item = $('.my-collaspible');
  var collapsed = true;

  $('.ui-btn').click(function() {

    item.one('collapsibleexpand', function() {

      collapsed = false;
      checkCollapsed();
      item.not($(this)).hide();
      $(this).collapsible('expand');

    })
    .one('collapsiblecollapse', function() {

      item.show();
    });
  });

  $(window).scroll(function() {

    if (!collapsed) {
      checkCollapsed();
      item.show();
      collapsed = true;
    }
  });

  function checkCollapsed() {
    $.each(item, function() {
     if (!$(this).hasClass('ui-collapsible-collapsed')) $(this).collapsible('collapse');
    });
  }
});
```

Comment: Thnak you , This is nice and fine , is it possible to show the items when scrolled down ??

Comment: You're welcome, what do you mean with 'scrolled down' exactly? I reckon you mean *scrolling down*...

Comment: Okay, added some lines for that that make all items collapse and visible. I'll have a second glance if there's anything that can be optimised still...

Comment: but  why i am getting a exception in console as <error> when i run this code . Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded

Comment: Any particular browser? Console is clean on Firefox. Edit -  I read that happens on Chrome. I'll see if I can figure out how that sticks together and fix it. Was tweaking to optimise it already. Probably scroll, that generally fires a lot. I'll update the answer.

Comment: I was working on that already (before the error report). Should be fixable. :-)

Comment: Thank you , but is this should be item.one or item.on ??

Comment: It is intended like this, each click will only fire the `collapsibleexpand` event a single time that way. This was the culprit overflowing the stack calls. https://api.jquery.com/one/